# Is there a way to check if an array holds more than one value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, netbeans, arraylist, integer

For example, what if I needed my code to have a certain set of numbers in an array list for something to happen? For example this array [1,3,4,5,9]. Is there any way I could check and see if an array contained all these integers at once and in the same order?

Comment: I would suggest to use a JS library such as [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) which has exactly [the method](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) you want

Comment: "which has exactly the method you want "  except that it doesn't test the order

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far. It's off topic to ask for recommended tools and libraries generally.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arraySearch = function (subArray,array ) {
    var i = -1;
    return subArray.every(function (v) {
            if(i != -1) {
                i++;
                return (array.indexOf(v) === i)
            }
            i = array.indexOf(v);
            return  i >= 0;
    });
};

var arr = [1,3,4,5,9];

console.log(arraySearch([4,5],arr))
```

Comment: You should switch the arguments, the names are confusing

Comment: yeah, changed again :)

Comment: You deserve an upvote for the effort, but note that the OP has not said if the search has to be for *contiguous* numbers, only that it was for *ordered* numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`{1,3,4,5,9}` is not an array. It's nothing valid in Javascript, for that matter.

`myArray = [1,3,4,5,9]` is an array. You can check the number of elements it contains with `myArray.length`.

> Is there any way I could check and see if an array contained all these
>   integers at once and in the same order?

For this, you will have to provide some code of your own and show what you've tried first.

Comment: Oh, an unexplained downvote, it had been a long time.

Comment: If I understood correct (which is hard BTW), OP want to check if one array contain another entirely. Note: I didn't downvote.

Comment: Yep but OP didn't provide any code and is expecting people here to give them the solution and develop stuff for them. That's not what we're here for.

Answer (score 0):

**Fundamental**

To check whether an array *contain an element just once*, 
you may simply check if both `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` yields exactly the same value and are greater then or equal zero.

```
var array = [1,2,3,3,3];

function isContainOnce(array,num){
    return array.indexOf(num)>=0 && array.indexOf(num)==array.lastIndexOf(num)
}

// Try it
isContainOnce(array,3); // false
isContainOnce(array,10); // false
isContainOnce(array,1); // true
```

**Now you can iteratively check the occurrence of such elements**

```
function isContain(arr,sub){
   var subArray = sub.slice();
   var k = null;
   while (subArray.length>0){
     var s = subArray.shift(); // Take the first element to test
     var i = arr.indexOf(s);
     var j = arr.lastIndexOf(s);
     if (i<0 || i!=j) return false; // Does not exist once
     if (k && i-k!=1) return false; // Not in order
     k = i;
  }
  return true;
 }
```

To check whether `[1,3,4,5,9,10,11,11]` contains a sub array `[1,3,4,5,9]` with all elements in the same order:

```
isContain([1,3,4,5,9,10,11,11], [1,3,4,5,9]);  // TRUE
```

Other cases

```
isContain([1,3,4,5,9,10,11,11], [5,9,10]); // TRUE
isContain([1,3,4,5,9,10,11,11], [2,3]); // FALSE
isContain([1,3,4,5,9,10,11,11], [10,11]); // FALSE because 11 occurs twice
```

Comment: The OP doesn't say "once" but "at once", so the whole code does probably not do what he wants.

Answer (score -1):

If it's for an exact match:

```
yourArray.toString() === "1,3,4,5,9";
```

If the numbers you're searching for are a subset of the array, possibly with extra numbers in the middle, you have to loop through the elements.

Comment: This will incorrectly return `true` for the array `[1,3,4,5,91]`.

Comment: @RodolfoAndrade good catch :-)

Comment: Fixed (and less assumptions about the not-quite-clear-question).